# Use a python module inside a custom module

Tags: python, python-3.7

I've built a custom module where store some functions of a project. 
Among these functions there is

```
{download_and_unzip_content(filename)}\
```

which needs the module tarfile.py in order to work. So in the main file of the project I have written the following code:

```
import tarfile
from custom_module import download_and_unzip_content
x = download_and_unzip_content(filename)
```

Unfortunately this leads to the following error

> NameError: name 'tarfile' is not defined

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
import tarfile
```

in the custom_module  py file.  import puts the modules named contents in to the CURRENT modules namespace under the name tarfile.  so when imported you can call the functions using syntax like tarfile.is_tarfile()